# Парсинг html страницы и применение функции indexOf  к русским частям текста.

Tags: java, синтаксический-анализ

Почему indexOf находит англисйкий текст, но не находит русский текст?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очевидно, что все дело в кодировке русских символов. Скажем: текст в БД/файле/сети лежит в кодировке UTF-8, а текст проги в кодировке Win-1251 (стало быть и паттерн поиска в кодировке Win-1251) - глупо ожидать, что поиск будет корректно работать.

В общем проверьте кодировки - никакой магии нет.

Comment: Истинная причина.